# Calculate standard deviation of merged sets with limited information (full details inside)

Tags: standard-deviation

I have:
A1: {3, 5, 6} and A2: {3, 4, 6, 8}

Avg A1: 4.(6)
Std.Deviation A1: 1.247

Avg A2: 5.25
Std. Deviation A2: 1.92

Merging A1 and A2, we get
A12: {3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 8}

Avg A12: **5**
Std. Deviation A12: **1.69**

I want to be able to obtain those values (avg and std. deviation for A12), having only the following information about A1 and A2:

**A1**
No. Elements: 3
Avg A1: 4.(6)
Std.Deviation A1: 1.247

**A2**
No. Elements: 4
Avg A2: 5.25
Std.Deviation A2: 1.92

Average is easy, 
(4.(6)*3 + 5.25*4)/7 = **5**

But I seem to be unable to calculate the correct std. deviation value.
I can only use the above information.
Any ideas?

Comment: How do you get standard deviations of 1.11, 1.75 and 1.4286? They look rather low.

Comment: oops, you are right, it is not. Awful mistake. will edit it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sigma$ is the (population) standard deviation then

$$\sigma^2 = \frac{\sum (x_i - \mu)^2}{n} = \frac{\sum x_i^2}{n} - \mu^2$$

so using the subscripts $1$, $2$ and $C$ for the first part, second part and combination

$$\sigma_C^2 = \frac{n_1 (\sigma_1^2 + \mu_1^2) + n_2 (\sigma_2^2 + \mu_2^2)}{n_1+n_2} - \mu_C^2$$

where $\mu_C = \frac{n_1 \mu_1 + n_2 \mu_2}{n_1+n_2}$ as you have.  Then take the square root.

I think this is easier to understand than [Wikipedia's version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Combining_standard_deviations) though theirs is better if rounding errors are an issue (e.g. with large means close to each other and small standard deviations).

Comment: it definitely is! thank you. :)